# iOS - Autolayouts elastic animation with constraints

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, constraints

Need to achieve elastic animation like

[image: desired output]

Dragging the view upward should show the view **beneath**(pink view in below gif) it. I have done the below gif animation using `UITableView` for demonstration. The effect was achieved using `UITableView` with clearColor as backgroundColor and `UITableViewCell` with white backgroundColor & parent view of `UITableView` is pink view.

Is it possible to achieve with two `UIView`s without using a table view or scroll view ? I have tried but it never worked with `UIView`s.

**Update**:
I want to achieve the below effect with 2 `UIView`s, lets say View1 & View2, View2 is child of View1. When View2 is dragged upwards, we should be able to see the View1. Hope this helps in understanding the question.

Comment: You can make it with ordinary UIScrollView, you don't have to make it with UITableView/UICollectionView (UITableView/UICollectionView does this because they are UIScrollView, this functionality is from UIScrollView)

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to make a scroll effect without scroll?

Comment: Have you tried to add gesture recognizer to view and move the view based on gesture values. Then animate it back to previous location?